# Do you need to be holding a Pearl of Power to use it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Does a character need to manipulate a Pearl of Power when recalling a spell, or does just having one in their possession give the caster that ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This DM would rule that a [*pearl of power*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pearl-of-power) only needs to be in the caster's possession for it to be used

The *pearl of power*'s description says, in part, "Once per day on command, a *pearl of power* enables the possessor to recall any one spell that she had prepared and then cast that day," and [Using Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Using-Items) on Use Activated says, "A few [magic items] must simply be in the character's possession (meaning on his person)."

Thus, while not *technically* a use-activated magic item, a *pearl of power* really does specify possession, making this definition of *possession* (and, in this context, so far as I'm aware, the *only* definition of *possession*) good enough for this GM.

So, despite being activated by a [command word](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Command-Word), this GM would allow a *pearl of power* to be activated even if still in the possessor's pocket or backpack, but, even if your GM agrees, ask if the *pearl* counts as being in your possession if it's in an extradimensional space like a [*handy haversack*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack).

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other usable item, I would think it would have to be held. You can't use a potion by having it in your possession but not out to be used. Neither can you you use a wand if it's in your backpack.
The only exception to this rule would be something that takes up a body slot- stuff like armor (because you're actively wearing it).